Does a ReadOnlySpan stop it's underlying managed array from being collected
I.E. is this safe:
    public static ReadOnlySpan<int> AFunction()
    {
        // localArray could be collected any time after this function returns if the ReadOnlySpan returned doesn't keep it alive.
        var localArray = new int[123];

        return new ReadOnlySpan<int>(localArray);
    }


The Span is tracked by GC when it looks for interior pointers of arrays. See linked post. Note that a Span cannot escape the stack.

Yeah I saw that question, and maybe its my head cold, but it was a bit too TLDR for me. I think the answer to my question is.. Yes?
